# Docker daemon start error on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, docker, digital-ocean

I followed all steps given in the [installation guide for Ubuntu 12.04](http://compositecode.com/2013/11/11/getting-docker-installed-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/)

But, it fails when starting the `docker` daemon:

```
~  sudo docker -d
[sudo] password for prat0318:
2014/06/10 02:26:34 docker daemon: 1.0.0 63fe64c; execdriver: native; graphdriver:
[29daee74] +job initserver()
[29daee74.initserver()] Creating server
[29daee74] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
2014/06/10 02:26:34 Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
Error running DeviceCreate (createPool) dm_task_run failed
[29daee74] -job initserver() = ERR (1)
2014/06/10 02:26:34 Error running DeviceCreate (createPool) dm_task_run failed
```

`Ubuntu` version (this is a Digital Ocean droplet):

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Linux Header version:

```
apt-cache search linux-headers-$(uname -r)
linux-headers-3.8.0-38-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Log while install of `lxc-docker`:

```
~ sudo apt-get install lxc-docker

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  aufs-tools cgroup-lite lxc-docker-1.0.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aufs-tools cgroup-lite lxc-docker lxc-docker-1.0.0
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 94 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,509 kB of archives.
After this operation, 18.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Get:1 http://get.docker.io/ubuntu/ docker/main lxc-docker-1.0.0 amd64 1.0.0 [4,404 kB]
Get:2 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe aufs-tools amd64 1:3.0+20111101-1ubuntu1 [98.8 kB]
Get:3 http://get.docker.io/ubuntu/ docker/main lxc-docker amd64 1.0.0 [1,786 B]              
Get:4 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main cgroup-lite all 1.1.5 [4,098 B]
Fetched 4,509 kB in 0s (7,336 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package aufs-tools.
(Reading database ... 88672 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking aufs-tools (from .../aufs-tools_1%3a3.0+20111101-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cgroup-lite.
Unpacking cgroup-lite (from .../cgroup-lite_1.1.5_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lxc-docker-1.0.0.
Unpacking lxc-docker-1.0.0 (from .../lxc-docker-1.0.0_1.0.0_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lxc-docker.
Unpacking lxc-docker (from .../lxc-docker_1.0.0_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up aufs-tools (1:3.0+20111101-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cgroup-lite (1.1.5) ...
cgroup-lite start/running
Setting up lxc-docker-1.0.0 (1.0.0) ...
docker start/running, process 15391
Setting up lxc-docker (1.0.0) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

I have tried to even reboot and logout/login from the vps, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: To help people who are still facing the issue, there is [a Github issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6325) that i filed earlier which has substantive discussion over it.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your Docker daemon is already running.

Check if the daemon service is running:

```
thomas@tmp:~$ sudo service docker status
docker start/running, process 2593
```

Ask the Docker daemon to report its version:

```
thomas@tmp:~# sudo docker version
Client version: 1.0.0
Client API version: 1.12
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 63fe64c
Server version: 1.0.0
Server API version: 1.12
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): 63fe64c
```